# .htaccess change url pattern

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

.htaccess boggles my mind. Here's what I am trying to accomplish.

We changed the structure of URLs from

http://www.example.com/products_new/%product-name%

to

http://www.example.com/products/%product-name%

What is the mod rewrite rule I will need to redirect all /products_new/%product-name% to /products/%product-name%

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^products_new/(.*)$ /products/$1  [R=permanent,NC]
```